# How to handle youtube ads with robot framework? to skip when theres an ad, wait when i cant skip or just pause if theres none?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to pause a youtube video, but sometimes there's an ad and sometimes ad may not be there (or sometimes theres 2 ads), so how can I identify and code it?

my currently code is like this

```
 click video
    Sleep  8s
    Click Button  ${SKIP_ADS_BUTTON}
    Press keys  none  SPACE
```

but when there's no id it fails and I don't know how to make it going or just wait... anyone?

ps: im using SeleniumLibary!

Comment: Are you using selenium?

Comment: yes im using selenium!

Comment: You can use Xpath to identify skip add button For more reference on how to find xpath: Follow this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-selenium-find-button-by-text/?ref=lbp

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer myself, this is how i did it:

```
  click video
    sleep  12s
    ${isElementExist}     Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   ${SKIP_ADS_BUTTON}
    Run Keyword If        ${isElementExist}    Run Keyword    click button    ${SKIP_ADS_BUTTON}    
    ...                   ELSE               sleep   15s
```